# XML serialize a dictionary

Tags: c#

I want Serialize Dictionary Collection ,but my code has error. Where I was wrong ?
this is my code.

```
Dictionary<country,string> Countries=new Dictionary<country,string>();

Countries.Add(new country() { code = "AF", iso = 4 }, "Afghanistan");
Countries.Add(new country() { code = "AL", iso = 8 }, "Albania");
Countries.Add(new country() { code = "DZ", iso = 12 }, "Algeria");
Countries.Add(new country() { code = "AD", iso = 20 }, "Andorra");

FileStream fs = new FileStream("John1.xml", FileMode.Create);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<country, string>));
xs.Serialize(fs, Countries);
```

class country

```
public class country
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int iso { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `XmlSerializer` does not work with dictionaries. Try making a `List<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`.

Comment: @Romoku Actually `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair` is not serializable, so you can't use it.

Comment: Yeah I usually make the struct or use a `Tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerializer cannot serialize a dictionary, but you can transform your dictionary in a list of KeyValue pairs and serialize it:

```
Dictionary<country,string> Countries=new Dictionary<country,string>();

Countries.Add(new country() { code = "AF", iso = 4 }, "Afghanistan");
Countries.Add(new country() { code = "AL", iso = 8 }, "Albania");
Countries.Add(new country() { code = "DZ", iso = 12 }, "Algeria");
Countries.Add(new country() { code = "AD", iso = 20 }, "Andorra");

FileStream fs = new FileStream("John1.xml", FileMode.Create);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<KeyValuePair<country, string>>));
xs.Serialize(fs, Countries.Select(x=>new KeyValuePair<country,string>(){ Key = x.Key, Value = x.Value}).ToList());
```

Edit:
Another thing to take into account: you can't use the `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair` struct offered by the framework because it is not serializable (the Key and Value properties are marked as readonly). You have to write your own KeyValue struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct KeyValuePair<K, V>
{
  public K Key { get; set; }    
  public V Value  { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `DataContractSerializer` option. It can serialize .NET Dictionary

[How to: Serialize Using DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675198%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)